# App framework intel for WindowsPhone, Android and IOS

Tags: android, cordova, intel, appframework

I am new with App Framework, I need experts suggestions, can I use APP framework for Hybrid app (WindowsPhone, Android, IOS ) without any panic with PhoneGap?
if not then Please suggest me best UI framework with PhoneGap,
I used JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 but its creating many issues in